# How can I check if servlet request is internal with Jetty?

Tags: java, jetty, jax-ws, embedded-jetty

We have a embedded Jetty 10.0.12 server, configure everything programmably (no `web.xml`) and already have a few servlets registered. We want to add a new servlet for an internal API. I have already done this. We now want to secure it. Security would be pretty simple: if the request did not come from within the server, reject it. This is good enough because we employ other security standards in the other servlets. I know where to start: create and register a filter:

```java
public class InternalFilter implements Filter {
  @Override
  public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // TODO: Check if request is internal.
    //       I.e., came from another registered servlet in the same JVM.
    //       If it is internal, then `chain.doFilter`.
  }
}
```

I do not know how to proceed from here.

Comment: If the servlet is being called only from the same process, why have a servlet at all?

Comment: We are writing an API that simply passes through to another. We will eventually replace it with our own API. Along with other reasons, it needs to be in its own servlet.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by assuming that "internal" means you are using either `RequestDispatcher.include()` or `RequestDispatcher.forward()`.

If so, then you can check the `HttpServletRequest.getDispatcherType()` value.

| Value | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `DispatcherType.FORWARD` | Request arrived from a call to `RequestDispatcher.forward()`. |
| `DispatcherType.INCLUDE` | Request arrived from a call to `RequestDispatcher.include()`. |
| `DispatcherType.REQUEST` | Request arrived from the beginning of the server handling tree. |
| `DispatcherType.ASYNC` | Request arrived from call to `HttpServletRequest.startAsync()` |
| `DispatcherType.ERROR` | Request arrived from error handling (either an unhandled exception, or from a call to `HttpServletResponse.sendError()` |